# Disk array power supply pinout/conversion

Tags: power-supply, reverse-engineering, pinout

Sorry for crossposting this, but I've had no answers from the more specific Ggroups.

I'm in the process repurposing a power supply from a scrapped Sun Microsystems StorEdge D2 array which was working perfectly well when decomissioned.

It is a Japanese made 360W FDK PEX737-40, +5V/30A and +12V/23A.
Impressively well built hardware and in mint condition.

The final objective is to have a PS with solid +12 and +5 outputs which may eventually power USB charging ports and other assorted stuff needing quality power.

The plug at the back of the slide-in box/canister has 24 pins just like the typical male Molex 39-01-2240 connector for ATX MBs but with a different pinout and keying(?) and without all the usual ATX voltages, which makes sense as it is not a for a motherboard.

Of the 24 pins, 20 have 18AWG and 4 have 24AWG cables.
All cables have their own pin assignment, no pin is used by more than one cable like, eg: sense cables in typical ATX PSs.

With the unit plugged in and switched 'off':

Logic wire resistance readings to GND

- 24AWG-green  ->    0.2 Ω
- 24AWG-brown  ->  530.0 Ω
- 24AWG-blue   -> 3610.0 Ω
- 24AWG-red    ->   60.0 Ω
- 18AWG-grey   ->   90.0 Ω

With the unit plugged in and the rear switch 'on' only:

- 18AWG-orange -> + 0.0006V to GND
- 18AWG-yellow -> + 0.0028V to GND
- 18AWG-grey   -> + 0.0004V to GND
- 24AWG-green  -> + 0.0000V to GND
- 24AWG-brown  -> + 0.0003V to GND
- 24AWG-blue   -> + 5.0800V to GND
- 24AWG-red    -> + 0.0003V to GND

The five +5V cables are on the same rail as they show 0.1 ohms between them, same for the three +12V cables.

The remaining red cable shows 10.2 ohms to the other +5V cables.

The yellow +12V cable shows 4.65K ohms with respect to the other +12V cables and is probably destined to one of the two redundant fans the array had.

With the unit plugged in, the rear switch 'on' and green+blue shorted, the unit latches_on and I get these readings:

- 18AWG-red    -> + 5.11V to GND
- 18AWG-orange -> +12.29V to GND
- 18AWG-yellow -> +12.01V to GND
- 18AWG-grey   -> + 5.06V to GND
- 24AWG-green  ->   0.00V to GND
- 24AWG-brown  -> + 5.11V to GND
- 24AWG-blue   -> + 5.08V to GND
- 24AWG-red    -> + 5.10V to GND

So I guess that the logic cable mapping would be this:

- 24AWG-green  ->  GND
- 24AWG-brown  ->  **?**
- 24AWG-blue   ->  PS_ON#
- 24AWG-red    ->  **?**
- 18AWG-grey   ->  PWR_OK

What I would need to know is:

The 24AWG-red cable has no voltage when the unit is not latched_on, so it does not seem to be +5VSB: what is it for?

Likewise, the 24AWG-brown cable has no voltage when the unit is not latched_on.

What would be the proper use of this cable?
Are they sense cables like the ones used in regular standard ATX PSs?

Do I need to put in a dummy load (10 ohm/5w sandbar resistor) to insure stability?

I'd be grateful for any input on this.

Comment: How does it match up to https://old.pinouts.ru/Power/sunauxpower_pinout.shtml

Comment: Was the 1st. place I liiked. I _know_ the voltages and all but two cables have their assigned use. It's a custom pinout. 24AWG red and brown have no voltage when the unit is off and +5.10V/5.11V with the unit on and I don't know where they go/have to go. Thanks.

Comment: Some PSUs have labeled on the pcb for each of the wires. You could open it. Or email the manufacturer. They sometimes throw hobbyists a bone on that.

Comment: I've opened it up and unmounted the PCB to check. Nothing useful, all labels are generic and (evidently) for manufacturer's use. The PS is a custom design for Sun and I've not been able to send FDK an email. Thanks for taking the time to write.